# Getting an error in .h file when trying to compile it. semi-colon missing

Tags: c, struct

```
struct MemPidsData
{
int PID[7];
}

struct MemInfoData
{
int heater;
int pump;
int fan;
int temperature;
int valve;
}
#define MEMORY_NAME_INFO "InfoMem" /* Common Memmory */
#define MEMORY_SIZE_INFO sizeof(struct MemData)
#define MEMORY_SIZE_PIDS sizeof(struct MemData)
#define MEMORY_NAME_PIDS "CommonMem" /* Common Memmory */
```

I am getting an error that semicolon is missing on the line where struct MemInfoData is defined... Please help..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually have *two* missing semicolons - it should be:

```
struct MemPidsData
{
    int PID[7];
}; // <<<

struct MemInfoData
{
    int heater;
    int pump;
    int fan;
    int temperature;
    int valve;
}; // <<<
```

Answer (score 3):

Always declare `struct` to end with `;`

```
struct MemPidsData
{
    int PID[7];
};
```